# Ajax get call returning entire html page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using a get ajax call and for some reason the get call is returning the html page instead of the JSON that is returned from userFactory.GetLast();.  I checked the method the route leads to and it return the last row from my db(which is what I want).  I want the get call to return the same.

Here is my jquery call

```
$('#Test').click(function(){
    $('#Get_Id').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $( this );
        url = $form.attr( "action" );

        alert(url);

        $.get( url, function(data){
          alert(data);
          console.log(data);
        });
    }); 
});
```

Here is the route in my .cs file

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("getLastEntry")]
        public IActionResult GetLastEntry()
        {
            ViewBag.Notes = userFactory.GetLast();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here is an image of what it returns
[image]

Comment: you are using `return RedirectToAction("Index");`...i believe you want to change that function to be a HttpGet Action item returning JSON...then return your object.

Comment: where is the method that returns "the JSON I want"?

Comment: userFactory.GetLast();

Comment: @abc123 thanks.  Post your answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Issue

you are using `return RedirectToAction("Index");`
This will return HTML

### The Solution

1 change that function to be a HttpGet Action item returning JSON
 2 then return your object